# AFNetworking POST not working

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I am trying to make a POST request using AFNetworking. I went through SO and found that I need to include  **httpClient.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding**

It still doesn't work even after making that change. Anything else I am missing ? Here is the code

```
NSDictionary *subDictionaryUsers = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:myObject.name,@"name",                                                     myObject.topic_description,@"description", nil];


    NSString *_restPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"spaces.json/auth_token=%@",myObject.auth_token];

    NSDictionary *params = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:subDictionaryUsers,@"space",nil];

        myAppAFNClient *httpClient = [myAppAFNClient sharedClient];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:_restPath parameters:params];

httpClient.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding;
    [httpClient getJsonResponse:request notificationString:@"add.hydramixer.topics"];
```

myAppAFNClient.m

```
-(void)getJsonResponse:(NSURLRequest *)_request notificationString:(NSString *)notifString{

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:_request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

        if([notifString length] != 0){
          // handling success
        }

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON){
        // handling errors
    }];

    [operation start];
}
```

Comment: What do you get back? Why are you not handling the error response if there is one?

Comment: It's not throwing any error. One of the reason I am stuck.

Comment: Did you check the response and the status code it provides? You have to give some indication of what happens.

Comment: That's the problem, the code executes, but doesn't give anything back at all. It's not even sending any messages to the server as well.

Comment: Is the operation getting created or it's nil ?

Comment: good call, let me check

Comment: $5 = 0x082a8a40 <AFJSONRequestOperation: 0x82a8a40, state: isExecuting, cancelled: NO request: <NSMutableURLRequest http://myRESTServer.com/ vkTA>, response: (null)>

Comment: Try `po [operation request]` to make sure the URL is correct.

Comment: You can also validate the request before creating the operation [AFJSONRequestOperation canProcessRequest];

Comment: I think it's probably the params, specifically the nested dictionary...

Comment: @AaronBrager, I see the right url that I wanted to see

Comment: @Wain, the thing is, it's not even executing the success block not error block.

Comment: Which suggests it's something to do with the request not being fully valid / processable.

Comment: (lldb) po httpClient
$1 = 0x082ac6e0 <rsHydraMixerClient: 0x82ac6e0, baseURL: https://myRestFulServer.com/, defaultHeaders: {
    Accept = "application/json";
    "Accept-Language" = "en;q=1, fr;q=0.9, de;q=0.8, ja;q=0.7, nl;q=0.6, it;q=0.5";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    "User-Agent" = "HydraMixer/1.0 (iPhone Simulator; iOS 6.1; Scale/1.00)";
}, registeredOperationClasses: (
    AFJSONRequestOperation
), operationQueue: <NSOperationQueue: 0x82acc10>{name = 'NSOperationQueue 0x82acc10'}>

Comment: I made a request using cURL and it's working fine and I am using the same URL and params. Not sure what's going on.

Comment: @Wain operation is not nil, I see all the information that's should be in there.

Comment: Instead of [operation start] try [httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];

Comment: BTW, I am looking at this thread
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/307
and started to wonder if really TestFlight is the problem ? I am using TestFlight SDK in my project as well. I haven't seen any fix in the thread above. Any thoughts on that ?